# AIR UrlMonitor doesn't dispatch StatusEvent.STATUS

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, url, air

As the title says, I've got a `air.net.URLMonitor` that sometimes doesn't dispatch a `StatusEvent` in case the specified site cannot be reached.

Let me show you my code:

```
_serverURL = "http://192.168.0.20:8080/"
_monitor = new URLMonitor(new URLRequest(_serverURL));
_monitor.pollInterval = 1000;
_monitor.addEventListener(StatusEvent.STATUS, serverStatusResult);
_monitor.start();
```

And here is my problem, when my iPad (this is a mobile AIR application btw) is in the correct network, so the one where the specified server is available, the StatusEvent is correctly dispatched. When I'm not in that network, nothing happens and I really don't know why.
Shouldn't it dispatch the event anyway?

This isn't an isolated issue, when our production environment server gets updated and isn't online, the same issue appears, however when the iPad is in offline mode and cannot reach the server because of that, the `StatusEvent` fires.

Is there a reasonable explanation for that, and if so, how can I correctly implement this?

Should I use a standard `HTTPService` instead and simply listen for ResultEvent and FaultEvent?

As usual, any help would be greatly appreciated!
Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

What do you have in your serverStatusResult function?

Something like:

```
public function serverStatusResult(e:StatusEvent):void {

if (! monitor.available) {

//connection has dropped so do something

}

}
```

I also found that setting a poll interval has a very detrimental effect on iPad CPU usage.

Comment: I'm using polling only during app start, so when the user isn't logged in yet. After that, the whole URLMonitor is disposed. Regarding the serverStatusResult function, yes, that's basically how that looks like. But as I said, it doesn't even get triggered.

Comment: I believe this will only get triggered when there is a CHANGE in the network connection. i.e. launch your app within a wifi signal, then take the iPad out of the signal so the connection is lost. This should trigger the status change.

Comment: If you want to check for a connection just try testing monitor.available

Comment: Unfortunately, the monitor's available status only changes after the StatusEvent has been fired, so it is always false before that, no matter whether the URL is available or not. Regarding the network change, yes, I found that too, however that makes the URLMonitor less of a solution for a simple up front connectivity check as you simply can't assume that the network interface will change before the app starts.

Comment: How about using a regular URLLoader to test something like www.google.com and see if you get a connection error?

Comment: Yes, that's what I've thought of as well (see my initial question, although I'd use a HTTPService) to quickly solve the issue. That would most definitely work, but I'm wondering if there isn't a way to make the URLMonitor work in the way I need it.

Answer (score 0):

The solution is very simple:
StatusEvent has a parameter called code.

Variable code is a string and it can be :

- "Service.available"
- "Service.unavailable"

Ok, now let's see an implementation:

```
public function serverStatusResult(e:StatusEvent):void {

switch(e.code)
{
case "Service.available":online();break;
case "Service.unavailable":offline();break;
}

}
```

Hope it helps :)